# Extracting UTM parameters value from first party cookie

Tags: google-tag-manager, session-cookies

I have passed the landing page's utm parameters to a first party cookie (using Simo Ahava's Persist Campaign Data GTM Tag) so I can track data from GA4.

first party cookie name - __gtm_campaign_url

first party cookie value - https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websiteabc.com%2Fen%3Futm_source%3Dfacebook.com%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26utm_campaign%3Dxxx%26utm_term%3Dyyy%26utm_content%3Dzzz

I need to get the value of the utm campaign (which is 'xxx') and store it in a variable using GTM. Does anyone can help me to achieve this?

I tried a javascript but I'm a noob at this.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).